# Refactor hardcoded variable across multiple classes into one global variable?

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring, hardcoded

(First time please be gentle etc. etc.)

Let's say I was lazy/unthinking/pressed for time and hardcoded a string instead of making a global variable. And I repeated this mistake over hundreds of classes and test cases that I wrote. Now, I want to fix this, since I found out I'll eventually need to update that string. Is there some refactoring method in Eclipse or elsewhere that will let me replace all instances of that specific string with a global variable?

I can think of a programmatic solution, to run through all those files and replace the string, but I'd prefer not to go down that route unless absolutely necessary.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you can use search and replace within Eclipse across all the files in your project, for one thing. You don't need to write that yourself.

It doesn't look like the "Extract Constant" refactoring of Eclipse is willing to extract it across classes, unfortunately. That would obviously be the nicer solution.

Comment: Right, I'm to used to using ctrl+f instead of the full project search. This should work fine after brushing up on regex for a bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse provide Refactor option.
right click on value which you want to replace with variable, you will see option Refactor.
this will help you replace value from all other occurance.

Comment: Yes, but only in a single file. This question was to do the same across multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

You can find referenced place to an element in eclipse as following:

1. Selected element.(variable of `String` in your case)
2. Sight click on selected element
3. Selected menu `References`
4. Select `Workspace` item for finding all references in your workspace
5. Then you can edit evry item in result

Exist another way such as using `search and replace` feature.